# Rails image not rendering inside li tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, paperclip

There is likely an easy answer to this, but I can't seem to figure it out. My blog image won't display in an li tag once my rails form is submitted with the image.

Is there a way around this? The image displays when the li tag is removed.

I would like to show multiple images though.

Thanks

```
<!-- Blog Entry -->
<div class="flexslider project-img">
  <ul class="slides"> 
    <li>
      <%= image_tag @post.image.url(:medium), class: "img-responsive" %>
    </li>
  </ul>                 
</div>
```

Comment: did some css hide the content from `li` elements in `ul.slides`?

Comment: You try test purpose without `ul` `li` tag & then see output

Answer (score 0):

Try to check in the developer tools to see if your ul tag styles are not causing a conflict with your `<li>` tags styles;

and l think this:

```
<div class="flexslider project-img">
```

is suppose to look like this:

```
<div class="flexslider">
```

I hope this helps.